# Save formatted (not serialize) json to disk to use git for storage

Tags: python, json, git, file, python-3.x

In working on a project where I will be using `OrderDict` to store the data the code will be working on.

However, I also want to save many of these `OrderDrict` as well as .json-files, and to to commit them to a git-enabled content repository.

But, since `json.dumps` just serializes and in effect place the JSON content on one line, it will make it tricky to track the difference between committed versions in a visually appealing way for users.

Is there a way to make `json` output better readable formatting, with indents and line feeds so the output-file can be easy to read, as well as taking better use of gits version and diff features?

Or are there any 3rd party libraries, preferable with Python 3.5 support, out there I've missed?

Comment: Try `json.dumps(..., indent=4)` perhaps?

Comment: I think the term generally used is pretify lots of ways of doing it. Try the above first otherwise some js function will do it for sure.

Comment: Thanks, will try @Blckknght's suggestion first.